# Can I tell who used iTunes on my iMac to sync while I was away?

Tags: itunes, imac, logs

Is there any way to see who used iTunes from my iMac with USB connection? Actually i want to see iTunes logs when someone get connected, synchronized or used my books?

Comment: Might be easier to change your password actually. USB syncing is logged but only on a technical level (device connected and disconnected), you won't even see the name of the connected device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to tell if a device has connected to your iTunes is to check the preferences and see if there is a device backup.  When you can connect a device to iTunes it creates a backup of the device (if you are syncing stuff to and from it).  In your case it sounds like you wanna find out if your books have been syncing to another device.

Open iTunes Preferences:

- Windows: Choose Edit > Preferences
- Mac: Choose iTunes > Preferences

There will be no way for you to see what specifically was sycned, this will only tell you if a device has synced, and when.

Comment: thank you. it seems that there is not any alternative to look at whether taking backup or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, iTunes maintains no log file of devices that have come to sync and that pairing is stored on each device as opposed to each computer.

For instance, if you connect an iPod touch to iMac A and sync contacts - the iPod remembers the hidden/internal ID of that iTunes library so that it knows to sync again next time it sees that library file (and not even that Mac).

Then if you connect the same iPod touch to another MacBook and sync music (and choose automatically sync rather than manual sync), the iPod remembers that its music came from a *different* library file. Again - the touch doest know the MacBook per-se but just the library file that was open in iTunes at the time it synced.

Thus way you can have one device sync different parts of its data with different users on the same computer and/or different libraries on different computers. The tracking is done on the iOS side of things and not on the computer end from what I've experienced.

The only edge case is if your devices are not set up to back up to iCloud in which case, iTunes may try to back up the device before starting a sync. I would start there, but it's not a guarantee that each synced device would have a backup (or even if there was a backup, it can be easily deleted).

You'd need some other tool to track things if you want to have a log of each sync event and/or catalog attached devices if you want to know what happens when you leave a computer unattended. It's far easier to inspect the contents on a device to see if it matches the content on a particular library (especially if DRM and/or personalized assets are transferred).